# Warning: React does not recognize the `FirstName` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router, react-hooks

I am getting the title error when opening a modal window.  I am getting the same error for LastName and PhotoFileName as well.

The file is called "EditEmpModal.js" and it looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

export class EditEmpModal extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={deps:[]};
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleFileSelected=this.handleFileSelected.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'department')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
        this.setState({deps:data});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered>

                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                        Edit Employee
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <Form.Group controlId="id">
                                    <Form.Label>ID</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="text" name="id" required placeholder="id" disabled defaultValue={this.props.id} />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group controlId="FirstName">
                                    <Form.Label>FirstName</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="text" name="FirstName" required placeholder="FirstName" defaultValue={this.props.FirstName} />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group controlId="LastName">
                                    <Form.Label>LastName</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="text" name="LastName" required placeholder="LastName" defaultValue={this.props.LastName} />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group controlId="email">
                                    <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email" defaultValue={this.props.email} />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group controlId="userlevel">
                                    <Form.Label>Userlevel</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control as="select" name="userlevel" required placeholder="userlevel" defaultValue={this.props.userlevel}>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                    </Form.Control>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <hr />
                                <Form.Group>
                                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                        Update Employee
                                    </Button>
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form>
                        </Col>

                        <Col sm={6}>
                            <Image width="200px" height="200px" src={process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.props.PhotoFileName} />
                            <input onChange={this.handleFileSelected} type="File" />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My apologies for the amount of code.  I tried to remove everything that did not seem relevant to the issue.

Does anyone see the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: User details are inside deps in state. Try this.props.deps.FirstName

Comment: Are you referring to within the render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just React is telling you that a prop you've passed a native DOM element doesn't exist, so you shouldn't expect it to do anything.

You usually see this message when you blindly pass all props to an element. This pattern is sometimes useful, but usually I find that its better to explicitly pass what it needs. This is where you are doing it:

```js
<Modal
  {...this.props} // <-- All props are passed to Modal
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
>
```

In order to figure out why this warns you, we have to explore the source code of `react-bootstrap`.

`Modal` passes all props that it does not explicitly expect to the `Dialog` component. You can see [here in GitHub](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Modal.tsx#L466).

```
<Dialog
  {...props} // react-bootstrap does the same thing here
  onMouseDown={handleDialogMouseDown}
  className={dialogClassName}
  contentClassName={contentClassName}
>
```

Then `Dialog` does the same thing to the final `div` to be rendered [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/ModalDialog.tsx#L81).

```js
<div
  {...props}
  ref={ref}
  className={classNames(
    dialogClass,
    className,
    size && `${bsPrefix}-${size}`,
    centered && `${dialogClass}-centered`,
    scrollable && `${dialogClass}-scrollable`,
    fullscreen && fullScreenClass,
  )}
>
```

So any prop that `Modal` or `Dialog` does not expect (as defined in the API documentation) will be passed to the underlying `div`.

A `div` does not use or expect the props `FirstName`, `LastName`, or `PhotoFileName` and therefore warns you about it.

Comment: You may be right - I probably should not have to do anything.  It's just annoying to see the warnings.  Funny thing is, I have another edit modal for departments, and I'm not getting any warnings over there.

Comment: Are there props you're actually needing to pass to `Modal` in `...this.props`? If not you can just remove the line, or you can pass the individual props you need. The warning can be removed, it's just up to you whether it's worth it.

Comment: When I remove the ...this.props line, the modal no longer opens.

Comment: What's in it? Is there an open or show prop or whatever `react-bootstrap` expects? I don't have the full picture, all I can say is the warning *can* be removed if you want. You would just need to go through your `props` and see which ones `Modal` needs and pass them manually to it.

Comment: Forgive me.  I am still a novice at ReactJS.  Is there a way I can console.log the props so I can clearly see what's in it?

Comment: Yep, `console.log(this.props)`. Probably best to do so in the `render` method, before the `return` statement.

Comment: Using console.log(this.props), it appears that everything is undefined.  id, FirstName, LastName, email, and userlevel are all undefined.